# Use candle stick count rather than resolution - Pine Script

Tags: range, resolution, pine-script-v4

Looking for a simple way to set my input for a cumulative volume range indicator to a specified amount of CANDLES rather than selecting a RESOLUTION to look back at.

```
is_new_day = change(time(cTimeFrame)) != 0 ? 1 : 0
cnt_new_day = barssince(is_new_day)

// Accumulation
cvol = 0.0
for i = 0 to cnt_new_day
    cvol := cvol + volume[i]

plot(cvol, "Cumulative Volume", style=plot.style_columns, color= color.yellow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to accumulate volume in one variable and reset it every N bar

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
length = input.int(1, "Length", minval=1)

cvol = volume
cvol += bar_index % length == 0 ? 0 : cvol[1]

plot(cvol, "Cumulative Volume", style=plot.style_columns, color= color.yellow)
```

Comment: ok, I'm so close! That totally works but what this does is set the range and then that prints off down the line resetting once it hit's that desired "length". What I want is to reset at every new bar so I always see the accumulative volume for length.

Comment: rather than than adding volume until I reach the "length", then resetting. I want the buffer to be full and when a new bar comes in, the old bar is pushed out.

Comment: This is just the sum over the last length bars, replace lines 5 and 6 by this `cvol = math.sum(volume, length)`